# IOS PWA getUserMedia not work in standalone mode

Tags: javascript, ios, progressive-web-apps

I have PWA application where I access microphone, in Safari all works fine, but when I add it to home screen it stop working. In manifest.json i'm using standalone mode, also i'm tried change this meta tag from yes to no `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="no">` but nothing help.

Answer (score 4):

getUserMedia [tweet-sized overview](https://twitter.com/firt/status/1112503403610017793)

If you want getUserMedia support for PWAs, chime in on [WebKit Bug 185448](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=185448).

See:

- [Progressive Web App Progress in iOS 12.2 Beta 1 (Build 16E5181f)](https://medium.com/dev-channel/progressive-web-app-progress-in-ios-12-2-beta-1-build-16e5181f-a18cd05ca361)
- [What’s new on iOS 12.2 for Progressive Web Apps](https://medium.com/@firt/whats-new-on-ios-12-2-for-progressive-web-apps-75c348f8e945)

Comment: Looks like it will be fixed in 13.4 